# The wc -w command outputs incorrect answer

Tags: grep, wc

I have to find how many times the word shell is used in a file. I used `grep "shell" test.txt | wc -w` in order to count how many times that word has been used, but the result comes out 4 instead of 3. The file content is:

```
this is a test file
for shell_A
shell_B
sh
shel
and 
shell_C
script project
```

Comment: Type `grep "shell" test.txt`, look at its output, and try to figure out what `wc -w` is doing with that input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The wc command is counting the words in the output from grep, which includes "for":

```
> grep shell test.txt
for shell_A
shell_B
shell_C
```

So there really are 4 words.

If you only want to count the number of lines that contain a particular word in a file, you can use the `-c` option of grep, e.g.,

```
grep -c shell test.txt
```

Neither of those actually count *words*, but could match other things which include that *string*.  Most implementations of `grep` (GNU grep, modern BSDs as well as AIX, HPUX, Solaris) provide a `-w` option for words, however *that* is not in POSIX.  They also recognize a regular expression, e.g.,

```
grep -e '\<shell\>' test.txt
```

which corresponds to the `-w` option.  Again, *that* is not in POSIX.  Solaris does [document](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=grep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=SunOS%205.10&arch=default&format=html) this, while AIX and HPUX describe `-w` without mentioning the regular expression.  These all appear to be consistent, treating a "word" as a sequence of alphanumerics plus underscore.

You could use a POSIX regular expression with grep to match words (separated by blanks, etc), but your example has none which are just "shell": they all have some other character touching the matches.  Alternatively, if you care only about alphanumerics (and **no** underscore) and do not mind matching substrings, you could do

```
tr -c '[[:alnum:]]' '\n' test.txt |grep -c shell
```

The `-o` option suggested is non-POSIX, and since OP did not limit the question to Linux or BSDs, is not what I would recommend.  In either case, it does not match *words*, but *strings* (which was OP's expectation).

For reference:

- [grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)
- [wc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/wc.html)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I tried to count a word that wasn't in the file, thinking it would output a 1 but it said 0 so I didn't give it much thought after. Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: And you'd have to be careful with (theoretical) input lines like "shell shell"

Comment: Explanation for wrong answer by "wc" is correct. Solution will not work if text contains "shell_shell shell_shell" , for which "grep -c" will incorrectly count 1. Only "grep -o" seems to be the best !

Answer (score 16):

The command 'grep' is outputting the entire lines that "shell" appear on.  Not just the word "shell." As can be seen below:

```
grep shell test.txt
for shell_A
shell_B
shell_C
```

I would recomend using the option

> -o, --only-matching

So:

```
grep -o "shell" test.txt | wc -w
```

Comment: Thank you good sir, now I am going to be off doing the rest of the hw

Comment: `grep -o` for the win!

Comment: Perfect solution !!!!

Answer (score 5):

since you can have the word "shell" multiple times on a line I would start with
breaking up the text in single words per line and then do the grep

```
< test.txt tr -s "[[:blank:]]" "\n" | grep "shell" | wc -w
```

you can also use `wc -l`, or do away with `wc` and use `grep -c "shell"`

And you can even remove the need for `tr` on the file that you have  and use:

grep -c "shell" test.txt

Comment: I find your answer erotic and love it.  But for someone new to shell scripting that involves a lot of complex subjects. Still got my vote

Comment: I should have thought of grep -c. I tried grep | c but i forgot c itself is not a command. I don't think I can get away with the other commands, those are not in the instructions.

Comment: @J.Doe Then leave out the `tr` as I showed in my update answer. `grep -c "shell" test.txt` gives you 3, but only because there are no double "shell"s on a line

Comment: Does not work if text contains "shell_shell shell_shell" , because only blanks are converted to "\n". Even "grep -c" will be incorrect. Only "grep -o" seems to be the best.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `wc -l` for that, i.e. `grep shell test.txt | wc -l`. That returns 3.

Comment: This suffers from the same issue as '-c' of not counting the occurrences and only counts the lines.  If "shell" appears two times or more on a line the answer will be incorrect